# Object class inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

We know that class A extends Object class implicitly but if we instantiate Object class object with class A constructor and try to access print() method of class A it shows a compile time error while in other case where class B extends class A and Class A object instantiated with class B constructor and try to access print() method works fine.

```
class A{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
class B extends A{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Object o = new A();
        o.print(); // error
        A a = new B();
        a.print();  // print B
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because the type of the variable `o` is `Object` and class `Object` does not contain a `print()` method.

Comment: Because `o` reference is of type `Object` which has no `print()` method. That's what we call static typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You example with class B extends A isn't the same as the case of A extends Object. The difference is that in the first case the superclass (`A`) contains the `print()` method, in the second case the superclass (`Object`) doesn't contain the `print()`. If you remove the `print()` method from the `A` class, the second part won't work either:

```
class A{
}

class B extends A{
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Object o = new A();
        //o.print(); // error
        A a = new B();
        a.print();  // error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
o.print(); // error
```

*You* know that `o` is **actually** of type `A`.

The compiler *could* know, but in Java, it does **not** know. The compiler only knows that there is some variable named `o`, of type `Object`.

Thus the compiler slaps your fingers for invoking a method on `o` that the **declared** type `Object` doesn't support!

Other languages are "smarter" about such things, but in Java, that is how things are.

Answer (score 0):

Because Object class does not have print() method and the reference o is of type Object, the compiler will throw an error.
In case 2 : class A has print() method thats why no compilation error and at runtime it calls class B's print() method because we assigned class B's reference at runtime.